# How to disable running automated Guard tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have enabled automated guard test in my application and now I want to disable it and run the tests manually. How do I do that?

Comment: Guard won't run if you just shut it down: `guard(main)> exit`.  From there, you can just run your tests manually.  If you don't want guard around at all any more, uninstall the gem.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you following some manual?

Comment: I am following Micheal Hartl's Ruby on Rails and this was exercise of Ch 3

Comment: @PaulFioravanti I am trying to execute: bundle exec rake test

Comment: What test framework are you running?

Comment: I'm using integration tests and controller tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following Micheal Hartl's book, go to `test/test_helper.rb` and remove the following two lines that you added while doing Advanced testing setup

```
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!
```

This should allow you to run the tests manually now.